# how do we get the span value if that attributes are same

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="label-column"> Your Renewal Charges</div>
<div class="ctrl-column">
    <span data-bind="html: DisplayTotalrenewalFee">
        <span class="CurrencySymbol">USD</span>
            810.00
    </span>
</div>
```

and in that same page have an another span value with same attribute (html: DisplayTotalrenewalFee)

```
<div class="label-column"> Amount Sent</div>
<div class="ctrl-column">
    <span data-bind="html: DisplayTotalrenewalFee">
        <span class="CurrencySymbol">USD</span>
            810.00
    </span>
</div>
```

only the difference

```
<div class="label-column">values
```

How can i generate an xpath for both to getting the value for USD and 810.00?

Comment: //div[@class="ctrl-column"]/span[@data-bind="html: DisplayTotalrenewalFee"] ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
(//div[@class='ctrl-column']/span[@data-bind='html: DisplayTotalrenewalFee'])[1]

(//div[@class='ctrl-column']/span[@data-bind='html: DisplayTotalrenewalFee'])[2]
```

for the first and second values respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can locate that span using the inner text of the required element.

```
By.xpath("//div[text()='Your Renewal Charges']/following-sibling::div//span[contains(@data-bind,'DisplayTotalrenewalFee')]")
```

or

```
By.xpath("//div[text()='Amount Sent']/following-sibling::div//span[contains(@data-bind,'DisplayTotalrenewalFee')]")
```

To know more about xpath and its functions [refer this](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/09/locating-webelements-using-xpath.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a list and then iterating through it.

```
List<String> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@data-bind='html: DisplayTotalrenewalFee']"));
for (WebElement element : elements)
{
    String usd = element.getText().split(" ")[0];
    String value = element.getText().split(" ")[1];
}
```

This can obviously be improved depending on what you want to do with these values.